# How to change one color to another in iMovie?

Tags: mac, video, imovie, color

I just started using iMovie on Mac for the first time. I've imported a single clip of a video I filmed of trees with sky above them. I applied a comic style filter, and now there is solid white around the trees where the sky is. I'd like to change the white to blue.

All I can find is a lot about green screens but that’s not how the video was filmed. I just want to change one color to another. Otherwise, is there a way of removing one color and adding a background behind it to achieve this?

Comment: I doubt that iMovie can do this. The problem is that the sky for sure is not *one* color but many different blues, so you need a mask or a keyer to tell the software to apply a certain effect to the video. DaVinci Resolve is a free option, Final Cut Pro X is the paid apple editing tool, of course there are others too. However, this is not as easy as it sounds like in the first place.

Comment: I did manage to figure that out after a lot more reading, I didn't know there was a free option though, thanks for the info.

Comment: So you managed to do what you asked for? Then put it down as an answer, so others can benefit too.